# Как запустить библиотеку используя dlopen?

Tags: c, sdl2

Код с сайта ([SDL2 - Tutorial - lesson 01](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php)), к сожалению, не могу вставить по причине того что не запрашивал разрешения на это. Вкратце - это "Hello world" на SDL2 - окрывает окошко и закрывает через пару секунд.

Собственно, может это возможно сделать с любым исходником C/C++, если скомпилировать его как библиотеку. Или я Ошибаюсь?

Скомпилировал с:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -lSDL2 -o libhelloSDL.so
```

предварительно изменив название функции main() в test_main().

Теперь пытаюсь запустить функцию test_main() c помощью dlopen():

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* заголовочный файл для работы с динамическими библиотеками */
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        void *ext_library;      // хандлер внешней библиотеки
        double value=0;         // значение для теста
        double (*powerfunc)(double x);  // переменная для хранения адреса функции

        //загрузка библиотеки
        ext_library = dlopen("./libhelloSDL.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!ext_library){
                //если ошибка, то вывести ее на экран
                fprintf(stderr,"dlopen() error: %s\n", dlerror());
                return 1;
        };

        //загружаем из библиотеки требуемую процедуру
        powerfunc = dlsym(ext_library, argv[1]);


        //закрываем библиотеку
        dlclose(ext_library);
};
```

Далее:

```
gcc test_dlopen.c -o test -ldl
```

И в терминале:

```
./test test_main
```

В результате предполагалось, что откроется окошко из примера с SDL2,
но этого не происходит. Ошибок тоже не выдает.

Comment: Под дебаггером запускать пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. Но я плохо в нем разбираюсь.